# Java JTable restructure / reload / refresh

Tags: java, jtable

I have a tree and a table on my panel, when I click the tree node, the table needs to change at the same time, but it doesn't. I search online and read the Java tutorial and didn't find any solutions. From some posts I think I need to use `fireTableStruetureChanged()`, but it just doesn't work in my code. Could anyone help me out of this? The following is the code. Thanks a ton!

```
public class tableStructureChange extends JFrame implements ... {
.....

/ //columnNames is a public variable, because I need to change the columns later
columnNames = new String[] {"col1","col2"}; */
data = new String[][]{
{"Mary", "Campione"},
{"Alison", "Huml"}, };

table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );

feedback = new JScrollPane(table);  //feedback is the bottom panel
```

...

```
}

//the following class is the problem, i need the table to be reloaded
//when the class is called, but the table doesn't change at all

public void displayFeedback(String tempString) {

//create table for bottom panel
columnNames = new String[] {"col3","col4", "col5"};
String[][] data = new String[][]{
{"Mary", "Campione", "us"},
{"Alison", "Huml", "canada"}, };
//table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
//fireTableStructureChanged();   //this is the problem part

}
```

// my table model
    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    String[] columnNames = new String[] {"col1","col2"};

```
public int getColumnCount() {
return columnNames.length;
}

public int getRowCount() {
return data.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int col) {
return columnNames[col];
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
return data[row][col];

}

}
```

...
    }

Comment: Could you please try and cut out irrelevant details in your code, so we can focus on the actual problem areas?

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for your reply. I edited the code and only leave the relevant code there. Could help me take a look at it. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method `displayFeedback` you seem to be hoping to replace the JTable object and have the display change to reflect what is selected in the `JTree` above.  Instead of replacing what is in the **View** object, you should focus your effort on updating the **Model**, in this case, the `AbstractTableModel` subclass that you have created.   There are  a couple ways you can do that, but for a brute force proof of concept, you could do something like the following:

- add a constructor to `MyTableModel` that takes a 2 dimensional array of `data`
- in displayFeedback, create a new instance of `MyTableModel` that has new data relevant to the tree node that was selected.
- call `setModel` on your global `table` variable.